# URLSession cache only

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, foundation

Sometimes I want to get data from the cache only when using URLSession. For example when quickly scrolling in a UITableView, I would like to show images that are already in the cache, but do not fire any HTTP requests. Images are just an example could be anything.

So I'm currently looking into URLSession's CachePolicy but it doesn't support an option to only get valid (not expired, etc) data from cache.

I can look into the URLCache myself, but this also of course returns data that might be expired. Is there some API that can validate a CachedURLResponse? Because then I can do it myself. Or do I have to implement the validating myself.

Comment: For Image Cache use SDWemImage Library

Comment: @ManishMahajan Images are an example could be really anything.

Comment: @inokey I think this is not a duplicate to the link you provided. I have added Images as an example for a HTTP request. Could be really anything. Also in the link he uses an extra Dictionary to have them in memory. I would like to avoid this as URLSession already does this in URLCache.

Comment: @Haagenti try looking into 304 http status code. I remember I used it to determine whether or not I should get stuff from cache. Unfortunately I can't remember more specific.

Comment: @inokey Mmm not sure if 304 status code will do the trick because in the cache just contains the original response which will most likely be a 200 response.

Comment: @inokey Also do you still think this is a duplicate? If so please elaborate, otherwise remove your comment because my question is now marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a fairly unusual request.  Normally, you're either writing code to operate in an offline mode (in which case you want to pull from the cache whether the cached results are still valid or not) or you are online (in which case you want to fetch new data if it isn't valid).

I would encourage you to really think long and hard about whether you really want to force cache validation if you aren't firing network requests.

That said, if you really want that behavior, there are two ways you can do it:

- Use `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad` and validate the age of the cached response yourself.
- Perform the request in a custom session, use `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`, and in that session, install a custom `NSURLProtocol` subclass that overrides `initWithTask:cachedResponse:client:` and `startLoading`, and calls `URLProtocol:didFailWithError:` on the provided client at the top of its `startLoading` method.

The second approach is probably the best option, because you don't have to worry about knowing all the esoteric rules for cache validation.  By making the actual load fail, the cache will work normally, but as soon as it actually would start making a network request, your custom protocol prevents that from happening.  And because you'll register the protocol only in that specific session (via the `protocolClasses` array on the session configuration), it won't break networking in other sessions.

Comment: NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad : "Use existing cache data, regardless or age or expiration date, and fail if no cached data is available". I would like only data when its valid.

Comment: Updated.  The custom protocol approach is *slightly* more complex, but still a lot simpler than cache validation.  :-)

Comment: I will implement your second approach which also sounds to me like the best option. Thank you.

Comment: You might find that this ends up working the same way as pulling everything from the cache.  If so, then the only option is #1.